# How do I launch the iTunes Store app from my application?

Tags: ios, itunes

How do I launch the iTunes Store app from my application? I want to take the user to a podcast page.

Answer (score 1):

Create a UIWebView, and put the link in so that when they press the button/link, it sends then to the URL for the web page. You'd think it'd open up in the webView, but usually iTunes automatically opens the iTunes app or the app store.

Need you learn how to use a webView? There are plenty of tutorials out there that can help. You can simply Google a tutorial, or search YouTube. Or, you can also post another question if you reach a problem.

Hope this is what you're looking for, your question was slightly confusing. If it isn't, I'd suggest revising your question slightly to specify.

Comment: Thanks! I know how to use UIWebView. But I thinks I have a problem: when I load the podcast URL in the mobile safari, it gets an arror, says the link is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go [here](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/) to get the URL for your podcast in iTunes.
2. Replace "http://" with "itms://" in the URL you got in step 1.
3. Put this code where you want to open your podcast:

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<URL FROM STEP #2>"]];

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just find the link of the podcast in iTunes and then encorporate the link in your application?